# Числовой массив, член-функции класса

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

**Задача**: написать класс с двумя параметрами: первый - степень, второй - массив коэффициентов. Количество значений в массиве должно быть равно степени + 1.

Проблема возникла с этим массивом. Не знаю, как его передавать, как в классе его применять. Привожу свой код. Постоянно то член-функции жалуются, то ещё что-то.

```
class Poly{
      int grade;
      int k_array;
   public:
      Poly(int, int[]);
      void Print();  
};

Poly::Poly(int tempX, int tempY[]){
        int grade = tempX;
        int k_array[grade];
        for(int i=0;i<=grade;i++){
            k_array[i] = tempY[i];  
        }
}
void Poly::Print(){
     std::cout << "Grade = "<< grade << endl;
     std::cout << "Array: ";
     for(int i=0; i<grade; i++) std::cout << k_array[i] << " ";
     std::cout << endl;
}
int main(){
//Для простоты я решил передавать коэффициенты так.
//При инициализации переменной в классе, последний уже сам разберется сколько ему значений нужно
    int arr[2]=0{2, 5, 3};
    class Poly a(2, arr);
    a.Print();  
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Вариантов решения задачи несколько. Можно банально передавать `std::vector` - его размер завсегда можно узнать. Также можно сделать конструктор у класса `Poly`, принимающим переменное кол-во аргументов(хоть бы и шаблонным, хоть и через `va_list`).

Comment: Я честно ни то, ни то не знаю. Можете показать что-либо из этого на примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть всё-таки это имеется в виду?

```
class Poly
{
    int grade;
    int *k_array;
  public:
    Poly(int tempX, int * tempY ) : grade(tempX)
    {
        k_array = new int[tempX];
        for(int i=0; i<=tempX; i++) { k_array[i] = tempY[i]; }    
    };
    ~Poly() { delete [] k_array; }
    /* .. */
};
```

Comment: @klopp почти. Только 

     k_array = new int[tempX+1];

Ну и вместо

     int arr[2]=0{2, 5, 3};

видимо

     int arr[]={2, 5, 3};

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо!